# Custom Cmake handling functions for build/clean

Tags: cmake, makefile

i'm new to cmake and I'm trying to find an option to commit the following

```
cmake .. && make && ./(project_name)   --> in order to run my code using 1 commnad
```

and

```
rm -rf *    --> in order to clean my build directory.
```

As custom commands to add to my cmake to use like MakeFile uses make all / make clean.

How would I approach this with building a custom command in Cmake to run ? is it even possible to do ?

Comment: The output of custom commands should already be added to the clean target. If this is insufficient, you could add additional files e.g. using the `ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES` properties. However this won't clean the cmake files; if you conditionally include a subdirectory based on a cache variable, the only way afaik for clearing the generated files would be to do exactly what you did: `rm -rf *` (or similar).

Comment: @fabian is there a need in each build to clean all the cmake files ? or is it only necessary when I change something in the config ? when changing the code do I need to recompile the entire cmake using : cmake .. && make && ./(project_name) ?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to clear anything. Usually cmake will even pick up on changed `CMakeLists.txt` files automatically, but you can also just pass the path to the directory where you've set up your cmake build as parameter to the command line tool and cmake will rerun the configuration with the existing settings. Reconfiguring should result in recompilation of those parts of your project where settings have changed (e.g. different compiler options, modified source files, ect...